# How does cabal convert flags to ghc options?

Tags: cabal, cabal-new

I have a cabal project, which I'm building with `new-build`. I have configured my library to use `-O0` when I pass a `dev` flag, and to use `-O2` for production builds.

The relevant stanza in my cabal file is

```
if (flag(dev)) || (flag(library-only))
  ghc-options: -O0
  cpp-options: -DDEVELOPMENT
else
  ghc-options: -O2
```

However, if I do `cabal new-build -f dev`, cabal passes the `-O1` option for some reason.

I can get around this by passing in `--disable-optimization`, but I'm curious why `-f dev` behaves this way

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is because cabal passes `-O1` by default, and adding the `-O0` flag doesn't tell it to not pass the other flag :-)